# Android getting never expire facebook user token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So, I have googled this, but all I get is how to generate never expiring facebook page token.

Scenario is this:
I want to log in user from my android application. Then, when he receieves token, that token will go to server. Now, what I want to do is this:
I want to make that token a never expired one, so I don't need to ask user to log in again from the application. Is this possible?

Comment: Take some SharedPreference variable and store whether user is logged in or not. If the user is not logged in then don't ask for login again.

Comment: @NigamPatro  And after 5 months when the token expires?

Comment: What is the need of token once user logged in?

Comment: please check this links https://www.rocketmarketinginc.com/blog/get-never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: @NigamPatro Getting info about user.

Comment: How many times you will get the info of user. Only once right?

Comment: @NigamPatro No, whenever user requests new info, lets say, whenever app is starting.

Comment: @AmeeJoshi think this is it, thank you!

Comment: When the user visits your app again, the SDK will see to it that you get a fresh token. There should be really no need for you to interfere here - especially considering that Facebook removed `offline_access` permission a while ago, because they _don’t want_ you to have user access tokens that are valid forever any more.

Answer (score 0):

Globals.java

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by Furkan on 28.10.2016.
 */

public class Globals extends Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();


    }

    private String token;
    public void setConfig(String key, String value) {
        try {
            SharedPreferences spref =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor spref_edit = spref.edit();
            spref_edit.putString(key, value);
            spref_edit.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("FD", e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public String getConfig(String key) {
        SharedPreferences spref =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        return spref.getString(key, "");
    }

    public void delConfig(String key) {
        SharedPreferences spref =     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor spref_edit = spref.edit();
        spref_edit.remove(key);
        spref_edit.commit();
    }


    public void clearConfig() {
        SharedPreferences spref =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor spref_edit = spref.edit();
        spref_edit.clear();
        spref_edit.commit();
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
        setConfig("token", token);
    }
}
```

this class will help you to save the token.

in your main class you should do;

```
Globals g;
```

after you reach the token you should save it like;

```
g.setToken(token);
```

and if you want to skip the login screen if there is a saved token you should do something like;

```
if(!g.getConfig("token").isEmpty()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, BlaBlaBla.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Good Luck !

Comment: Thank you. Now, if the token I have expires, how to obtain another one without logging in?

Comment: @MiljanVulovic i think it never expires. can you tell me a scenario? then I will think about it